# Renaming files using PowerShell always throwing error path does not exist even path are correct in csv files & on windows

Tags: powershell

I am trying to rename files based on csv inputs but it always throwing error path and file does not exist. Below is the CSV sample, can any one guide what exactly I am doing wrong her, sugguset me a right direction.

[image]

Getting below Error

```
- rename-item : Cannot rename because item at 
'\\localhost\NG\storage\Managed\553553\Office\830FFE47-98BD-4FB7-9ED3-5C986ACD00F1\7F467B52-40FA-43AC-AC8B-CFD67241BDC5\7431DFD2-0B98-4081-B36D-185E84FB3B69\deeaeb40-98d4-45c4-a524-f7634730142b.csv' 
does not exist.
At C:\Users\sanjay.nakhate\Desktop\Untitled2.ps1:17 char:3
+   rename-item -LiteralPath $file.FullFilepath -newname $file.NewFileN ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

```
#[System.IO.File]::Exists($path)
 
$files = Import-Csv "C:\RenameFileNameInput.csv"

foreach ($file in $files) {
    try {
        if (!(Test-Path $file.Filepath) -and !(Test-Path $file.$Filepath)) {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "File path not exist " $file.FullFilepath 
        }
        else {
            Rename-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullFilepath -NewName $file.NewFileName

            Write-Host "File Renamed " $file.ServerRelativeUrl 
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Rename action complete"
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Error Occured " $file.FullFilepath 
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `-and !(Test-Path $file.$Filepath)`. Nothing is ever assigned to `$Filepath`, so `$file.$Filepath` is equivalent to `$file.''` - which evaluates to `$null`

Comment: not its going in catch block and renaming the file. looks like there is some issue in rename command

Comment: Consider re-throwing the error (just do `throw` without any arguments inside the catch block) to see what actually happens

Comment: after adding throw in catch block not showing any thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution after spending some time on it.

```
    $files = Import-Csv "C:\RenameFileNameInput.csv"

foreach ($file in $files) 
{

try
{

if(Test-Path $file.FullFilepath -PathType Leaf)
{

  rename-item $file.FullFilepath -newname $file.NewFileName
  Write-Host "File Renamed off" $file.OldFileName "To" $file.NewFileName 
  Write-Host -foregroundcolor green "Rename action complete"
 
}

else

  {

  Write-Host -foregroundcolor red "File path not exist " $file.FullFilepath 

  }
}

catch
{

Write-Host -foregroundcolor red "Some error occured " $file.FullFilepath 

}

}
```

Comment: `Rename-Item -Path $file.FullFilepath -NewName $file.NewFileName -ErrorAction Stop` # Add ErrorAction Stop to invoke try-catch

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $path)) {
        throw ("Path not found {0}" -f $path)
    }
    
    $files = Import-Csv "C:\RenameFileNameInput.csv"

    foreach ($file in $files) {
        try {
            if (-not (Test-Path $file.Filepath)) {
                Write-Host  "File path not exist " $file.FullFilepath -ForegroundColor Red  
            }
            else {
                Rename-Item -Path $file.FullFilepath -NewName $file.NewFileName -ErrorAction Stop # Add ErrorAction Stop to invoke try-catch
                Write-Host ("File Renamed {0}" -f $file.ServerRelativeUrl)
                Write-Host  "Rename action complete" -ForegroundColor Green
            }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host  ("Error Occured {0}" -f $file.FullFilepath) -ForegroundColor Red  
            $_ | Format-List * -Force
            $_.InvocationInfo | Format-List *
            $Exception = $_.Exception
            for ($i = 0; $Exception; $i++, ($Exception = $Exception.InnerException)) {
                "$i" * 80
                $Exception | Format-List * -Force
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: still getting bellow error still wondering that file is there & i am able to access this path and file over on this i put file in deferent locations still it's giving error on below path                               Exception             : System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException: Cannot rename because item at 'C:\Renamedeeaeb40-98d4-45c4-a524-f7634730142b.csv' does not exist.

Comment: its having white space in path \\localhost\NGShare\storage\Managed\553553\Office\830FFE47-98BD-4FB7-9ED3-5C986ACD00F1\7F467B52-40FA-43AC-AC8B-CFD67241BDC5\7431DFD2-0B98-4081-B36D-185E84FB
                 3B69\

Comment: now getting this error- Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Users\sanjay.nakhate\Desktop\Untitled3.ps1:1 char:27
+ if (-not (Test-Path -Path $path)) {    earlier the issue with file name it was wrong